# In Flutter how can we able to get the data between specific date ranges using firebase if we had date parameter in firestore?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is there any way to get the data in between the dates like for one week, a month, or something like some date range?

Can we extract the data using a simple query or is there any complicated procedure to get those firestore data?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [compound queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#compound_queries) to achieve what you want to do:

```
collection  
.where("date", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: date)
.where("date", isLessThanOrEqualTo: dateEnd);
```

Where date is the start date of your range and dateEnd is the date at the end of your range (e.g. one week later).